# Dutch citizenship

Tags: citizenship, netherlands

My father was born in South Africa in 1952. Both his parents were Dutch citizens.

Is it possible for him to obtain Dutch citizenship, or does the rule still apply where there is a 10 or 13 year lenience period from when he turned 18?

Comment: Did your father's parents ever naturalize in South Africa?  Did your father ever live outside of South Africa?  Did your father ever work for the United Nations or a similar international organization?  There are many factors to take into account, and the factors changed over the years.  Basically it's likely that he was a Dutch national at birth and likely that he no longer is, but there is a slim possibility that he never was or that he still is.

Comment: Welcome to Expatriates. What have you discovered so far from your [own research](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)? There are already quite a few questions about Dutch nationality on this site, try searching using tags eg [citizenship], [netherlands], [south-african-citizens] etc